# Proxy Routing Mechanism

Tags: proxy

a general question about internet proxies.
we have several proxies at work. Each of them has its own list of allowed sites.
Is there a way to setup "something", tell this "something" that the proxies are x,y,x and let this "something" resolve the whole thing. Something like a proxy routing mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burp Proxy can be used as an interceptor for security testing of web applications. It is like a man-in-the-middle between a browser and the target application. Check if that serve your purpose...

http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html

Comment: this is exactly the what i was looking for. I have found another application named proxifier. Thanks shamli!